# How to use Two Where Clauses use in Php Mysql Search?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

**PHP/MYSQL:**
  How To use Normal Where Clause And Search Where Clause Use to Mysqli Query

```
$search = $_POST['cloud_edge'];
$cloud_edge = 1;

 $network_countries = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * From media_networks   WHERE 
 cloud_edge = "'.$cloud_edge.'" AND capital_city LIKE "'%$search%'"  ORDER by 
capital_city  ');
```

Comment: explain better  .. you have error?

Comment: Yes.no Data of Array

Comment: Are you sure you're using the correct `$_POST` parameter? It seems strange that the variable `$cloud_edge` doesn't come from `$_POST['cloud_edge']`.

Comment: `LIKE "'%$search%'" ` need to be `LIKE "%'.$search.'%" `

Comment: Please see this link. https://gist.github.com/rfmeier/6139836

Comment: Your open to SQL injection. https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks

Comment: Thanks Lawrence Cherone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $network_countries = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * From media_networks   WHERE 
 cloud_edge = "'.$cloud_edge.'" AND capital_city LIKE "%'.$search.'%"  ORDER by 
capital_city  ');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing concatenation on second variable.

```
<?php
    $search = $_POST['cloud_edge'];
    $cloud_edge = 1;

     $network_countries = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * From media_networks   WHERE 
     cloud_edge = "'.$cloud_edge.'" AND capital_city LIKE "%'.$search.'%"  ORDER by 
    capital_city  ');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate search variable properly

```
LIKE "%'.$search.'%"
```

Also you can't add `%` with variable it won't return the result. Try following

```
$network_countries = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * From media_networks   WHERE 
 cloud_edge = "'.$cloud_edge.'" AND capital_city LIKE "%'.$search.'%"  ORDER by 
capital_city ');
```